# Сортировка и обращение к файлам

Tags: cmd

Имена файлов в папке будут содержать номер в начале и пробел после него. Например, 01 script, 1 script ... n script. Нужно в цикле обратится ко всем файлам в порядке возрастания их номера. Как это сделать?

На данный момент вот что я имею:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
c:
cd C:\test
for /F "eol=# delims=, tokens=1*" %%i in ('dir /a:-d/b/s') do echo ^"%%i^"
pause
cls
@echo on
exit
```

Тут нету сортировки, я так понимаю, файлы и так обрабатываются в отсортированном порядке?

Если мне нужно выполнить команду то мне заменить echo? И можно ли туда впихнуть 2 команды? Файлы я получаю в отсортированном порядке?